# out parameter and "ShowMessage" function

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have a function declare like this :

`function execProc(ProcName,InValues:PChar;out OutValues:PChar):integer;  //The "OutValues" is a out parameter.`

And I call this function like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 v:integer;
 s:pchar;
begin
 Memo1.Clear;
 v := execProc(pchar('PROC_TEST'),pchar('aaa'),s);
 showmessage(inttostr(v)); //mark line
 Memo1.Lines.Add(strpas(s));
end;
```

when i delete the mark line(showmessage(inttostr(v))),i will have a correct result display in the Memo1,but if i keep use the showmessage(), the memo1 will dispaly an error string : "Messag" ,Why?
Thanks for any help!

```
function execProc(ProcName,InValues:PChar;out OutValues:PChar):integer;
var
  str: TStrings;
  InValue,OutValue: string;
  i,j,scount: integer;
begin
Result := -100;
i := 0;
j := 0;
str := TStringList.Create;
try
  sCount := ExtractStrings(['|'], [], InValues, str);
  with kbmMWClientStoredProc1 do
  begin
    Close;
    Params.Clear;
    StoredProcName := StrPas(ProcName);
    FieldDefs.Updated := False;
    FieldDefs.Update;
    for i := 0 to Params.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if (Params[i].ParamType = ptUnknown) or
       (Params[i].ParamType = ptInput) or
       (Params[i].ParamType = ptInputOutput) then
      begin
        inc(j);
        InValue := str[j-1];
        Params[i].Value := InValue;
      end;
    end;
    try
      ExecProc;
      for i := 0 to Params.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if  (Params[i].ParamType = ptOutput) or
       (Params[i].ParamType = ptInputOutput) then
         OutValue := OutValue + '|' + Params[i].AsString;
      end;
      OutValues := PChar(Copy(OutValue,2,Length(OutValue)-1));
      Result := 0;
    except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
        if E.Message = 'Connection lost.' then Result := -101;//服务器连接失败
        if E.Message = 'Authorization failed.' then Result := -102;//身份验证失败
        Writelog(E.Message);
      end;
    end;
  end;
finally
  str.Free;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Can you show implementation of `execProc`. If it is a function in an external DLL, please show its declaration from the C header file.

Comment: Thank you @DavidHeffernan, I have edited my problem description and added the  implementation of `execProc` after the description.

Comment: Thank you. I have added an answer which explains what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the design of your interface and the use of `PChar`.

```
OutValues := PChar(Copy(OutValue,2,Length(OutValue)-1));
```

This is implemented by making an implicit, hidden, local string variable which holds the value

```
Copy(OutValue,2,Length(OutValue)-1)
```

When the function returns, that string variable is destroyed and so `OutValues` points at deallocated memory. Sometimes your program appears to work but that's really just down to chance. Any small change can disturb that, as you have observed.

The problem is easy enough to fix. Simply use string parameters rather than `PChar`. This will make the code easier to read as well as making it work correctly.

```
function execProc(ProcName, InValues: string; out OutValues: string): integer;
```

Comment: David,I have know what you mean,thank you very much!But in fact, i want declare all the function in an external DLL for other application call,so i must use the `PChar` variable,how to fix this problem through any other way?

Comment: Well, that's a different question now. An easy fix would be to use `WideString` since that ensures that all parties use the same shared COM allocator. A trickier fix would be to arrange for the caller to allocate the memory and then let your function populate the buffer. But an out parameter of type `PChar` is probably never the answer.

Comment: Thanks David!Your another answer is very useful :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331026/why-can-delphi-dlls-use-widestring-without-using-sharemem